# declared variable doesn't seem global

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared my variable first - then have my jquery :

```
var cimg = '';
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".trigger").click(function() {
  var cimg = event.target.id;
  clickedimage();
  loadPopup();
});
});
```

Then the script outside the jquery :

```
function clickedimage()
  {
    var xmargin  = $(cimg).width()/2;
    var ymargin = $(cimg).height()/2;
    $("#popupimage").css('margin-left',-xmargin+'px')
    $("#popupimage").css('margin-top',-ymargin+'px')
    var Clicked = cimg.src;
    $('#popupimage').attr('src',Clicked);
  }
```

It doesn't seem to want to take on the cimg value supplied from the `.trigger` clicked event

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the click event you do `var cimg = ...;`.  The `var` keyword tells it to create a new local variable instead of using the one from the outer scope.

Remove the `var` inside the handler.

```
var cimg = '';
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".trigger").click(function(event) {
        cimg = event.target.id;
        clickedimage();
        loadPopup();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason my cimg value (the element id) wouldn't work with the variables/css writes i have? If I alert cimg I get the proper selected image id, but it doesn't seem to want to write the css or attributes appropriately.

Comment: @rootsup: You're doing `$(cimg)`.  `cimg` does *not* contain a valid jQuery selector.  You need to do: `$('#'+cimg)`.  Also `cimg.src` won't work since `cimg` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You redeclaring `var cimg` which causes it to be a local variable inside function scope. In addition, you're not providing `event`, which also causes an error (some browsers allow referring to window.event though).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".trigger").click(function(event) {
        cimg = event.target.id;
        clickedimage();
        loadPopup();
    });
});
```

Comment: could i declare event as so? "click.target.id;" ? or how would i append this?